# Error 'Do not use findDOMNode'; how to fix the code so it doesn't complain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript class that is in my react project.

Basically, i wanted to add a sunburst pie chart to my UI. So I put the code for it in my react project. At compile time (i.e. when i run npm start) I get the error

```
error    Do not use findDOMNode                       react/no-find-dom-node
```

I read online but I still don't completely understand this error (or what findDOMNode does, for that matter).

I simply need to fix the code for findDOMNode to whatever it needs to be, as for now I am just disabling the rule.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Sunburst from "sunburst-chart";
/* eslint-disable react/no-find-dom-node */
/* eslint-disable no-console */

const data = {
  name: "main",
  color: "magenta",
  children: [
    {
      name: "a",
      color: "yellow",
      size: 1
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      color: "red",
      children: [
        {
          name: "ba",
          color: "orange",
          size: 1
        },
        {
          name: "bb",
          color: "blue",
          children: [
            {
              name: "bba",
              color: "green",
              size: 1
            },
            {
              name: "bbb",
              color: "pink",
              size: 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
class SunburstChart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      myChart: Sunburst().data(data)
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // set el height and width etc.
    this.state.myChart(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
  render() {
    return <div id="chart" />;
  }
}
export default SunburstChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will eventually deprecate findDOMNode as it blocks certain improvements in React in the future.

It is recommended to use callback refs instead. See Dan Abramov comments and examples here:
https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220

source: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-find-dom-node.md

Comment: Please quote your answer properly. https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-find-dom-node.md .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out after reviewing the github links

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // set el height and width etc.
    this.state.myChart(this.node);
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
  render() {
    return <div id="chart" ref={node => this.node = node}/>;
  }
```